# Avoid Sidekiq workers to be concurrent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am currently running Sidekiq on a small dyno at Heroku. Performance is great to perform simple tasks like checking data, sending emails ..

Though I have recently asynced some image manipulation with ImageMagick and the load seems too big for my current concurrency.

Here is my Sidekiq.yml :

```
development:
  :concurrency: 5
production:
  :concurrency: 4
:queues:
  - critical
  - default
```

When 4 image versionning are fired together the workers stay forever in the queue, They complete alltogether in about 20minutes.

If I set production concurrency to 1, the 4 workers are processed in about 20 seconds. (5 seconds each sequentially)

Is there a way to have specific workers not being processed concurrently so that I can keep a concurrency of 4 but still have the image versionning not choke the little dyno ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run two sidekiq runners, one specialized for your image processing job, which does not work concurrently, check [the documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#reserved-queues) for specifics.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I have to play with `-c` tag in order to attribute the right concurrency to each queue. Also I guess I  need two workers .. I will keep a global concurrency of 1 at the moment and switch to two workers with above setup when one worker is not enough anymore..